# Fetch large data set from Database and Send it to Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have 2 tables lets say Emp and Courses table. Emp has 30k rows and Courses have 100k rows.

1 employee can have many courses .i.e one to many relation.I need to fetch the records from the table and send to a Kafka.

```
Data From Table-----> Convert To JSON --->Send To KAFKA
```

I don't want to load all the rows in the memory at once as it can cause memory out of exception error.

How to achieve it? I will probably be using JDBCTEMPLATE or SPRING DATA JPA?

I am using **SPRING BOOT 2+ version and JAVA 8**

FYI 
For eg. in EMP table i have emp_id =1 which has 5 corresponding rows in Courses table.
So i will convert this 5 rows to 1 Java object and then 1 Json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing data from a database to Apache Kafka is a really common use case. [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) allows you to stream data from and to Kafka in a reliable, scalable and fault tolerant way. Specifically, the [JDBC source connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/) does what you are trying to do, if you build your custom solution you'll probably end up having a partial implementation of what the connector is already doing.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data provides a feature to load a lot of data continuously in a non-blocking way. This allows you to do all the treatments you want on your results while some data are still fetching. To do that, you just have to return a Stream of your @Entity class :

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, String> {
    Stream<EmployeeEntity> findAllBy();
}
```

Comment: will the setfetchsize() help in my case